# Call shouldChangeCharactersInRange on app init, not just when user enters text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that formats phone numbers to add dashes between the area code and after 3 digits.  The problem is that the data im using isn't pre-formatted.  So when the app laods initially, the phone numbers appear unformatted, until someone types in the text field.

Is there a way to extend the functionality of shouldChangeCharactersInRange to be called on init of the app & when a user types?

Here is my shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == _phoneNumber.tf)
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSArray *components = [newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
        NSString *decimalString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        NSUInteger length = decimalString.length;
        //BOOL hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && [decimalString characterAtIndex:0] == '1';


        if (textField.text.length > 11 && range.length == 0)
        {
            return NO; // Change not allowed
        }
        else
        {
            //if (length == 0 || (length > 9 && !hasLeadingOne) || (length > 10))
            if (length == 0 || (length > 10))
            {
                textField.text = decimalString;
                return NO;
            }

            NSUInteger index = 0;
            NSMutableString* formattedString = [NSMutableString string];

            if (length - index > 3)
            {
                NSString *areaCode = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
                [formattedString appendFormat:@"%@-",areaCode];
                index += 3;
            }

            if (length - index > 3)
            {
                NSString *prefix = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
                [formattedString appendFormat:@"%@-",prefix];
                index += 3;
            }

            NSString *remainder = [decimalString substringFromIndex:index];
            [formattedString appendString:remainder];

            textField.text = formattedString;
            //NSLog(@"** Formatted Phone: %@", formattedString);

            numLength = formattedString.length; // 12 Characters including dashes
            //NSLog(@"** Formatted Length: %lu", (unsigned long)numLength);
        }


        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the logic that does the evaluation into its own method, modify it to act on a string parameter instead of `textField.text`, and call it from both this method and from your initialization.